# mysql + all numbers from one field to Sum

Tags: mysql, string

Is it possible to sum the digits in a string and sort by that?

```
Example values: 19, 21
19 Should be transformed to 10. Explanation: 1+9=10
21 Should be transformed to  3. Explanation: 2+1= 3
```

After calculating these results, the table needs to be sorted by the resulting values (using `SORT BY`).

Originally, I have those values stored as JSON array, so it's `["1","9"]` and `["2","1"]`, and in order to parse the JSON I'm using replace as follows:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(item_qty, '["', ''),  '"]', ''), '","', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like:

```
SELECT (
    SUBSTRING('["1","9"]', 3, 3) +
    SUBSTRING('["1","9"]', 7, 7)
) AS sumOfDigits;
```

And then if the value `["1","9"]` is stored in a column named `json` and the table is named `table` you van do:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT table.*, (
        SUBSTRING('json', 3, 3) +
        SUBSTRING('json', 7, 7)
    ) AS sumOfDigits
    FROM table
) tmp
ORDER BY sumOfDigits;
```

Comment: The problem with that, the numbers in json are dynamic, and can be very different, it can be ["12","9","23"] or just ["1"]

Answer (score 0):

I would define a function to do the sum, as follow:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION add_digits
  (
    number     INTEGER
  ) RETURNS INTEGER

BEGIN
  DECLARE my_sum INTEGER;

  SET my_sum = 0;

  SET number = ABS(number);

  WHILE (number > 0) DO
    SET my_sum = my_sum + (number MOD 10);
    SET number = number DIV 10;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN my_sum;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

You could also create a function that works directly on your json sting, parsing it for digits and adding their values.

Comment: It has to be MySQL query

Comment: I meant a stored function, called as part of the query. The function above can be called as SELECT `add_digits(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(item_qty, '["', ''),  '"]', ''), '","', '')) FROM ...`

So could a stored function working directly on item_qty.

Comment: I need to use it as a mysql query in php, i'm not sure if there is a way to store a mysql function, and I need to use for ORDER BY, not select. thanks for trying